# How do I Remove or Strip off all the way up to delimiter

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to modify a response field (Result).  The response value looks like this,

```
id%#%Path123
```

Here `id` gets assigned from the login, so, it will be different for each user. I've added that delimiter (`%#%`) in the interest of being able to remove the id.
I'd like the requester to get to see only `Path123`.  Basically, strip off `id%#%` before it gets to the requester.

I have tried this,

getResult();

setResult(result.replaceAll("%#%", ""));

But not much luck with `replaceAll` function.

Which function will allow me to remove all the way up to the delimiter and only display Path123?

Comment: Have you spent any time at all reading the javadoc for the String class?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that %#% comes only once and you want to get the substring after the %#%
you can do something like this..

```
"id%#%Path123".split("%#%")[1]
```

Comment: I need to remove all the characters until and including the delimiter (%#%).

Comment: id%#%pathvalue is the response.  here id and value changes.  i included the delimiter, to separate the id from value.

Comment: The above code will remove all the characters until and including the delimiter (%#%)...Did you try to run? if you did what is the output that u get...I am getting the "Path123"..which is what u want..

Answer (score 0):

Read the String class javadocs. Look for the methods indexOf and substring